# React.useState() hook doesn't reflect new value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

QUESTION: **Why my setContact() function doesn't work?**

My hook declaration:

```
const [contact, setContact] = useState({
fName: "",
lName: "",
email: ""});
```

My UI element:

```
<input
      name="email"
      placeholder="Email"
      onChange={catchEmail}
      value={contact.email}
    />
```

My onChange handler:

```
function catchEmail(event) {
const { value: email } = event.target;
setContact((prevValue) => {
  prevValue.email += email;
  return prevValue;
});
```

}

I know how to make it work, but I want to understand what's wrong with this code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing the DOM is (sometimes) expensive. React, understanding this, does not re-render components if the new state is exactly the same (`===`) as the old state.

Here, since you're mutating the existing state and returning it, the new state is the same object as the old state, so React skips re-rendering.

You need to return a *new* object, so React knows to re-render.

```
setContact(prevValue => ({
  ...prevValue,
  email
}));
```

(you don't want to concatenate onto the existing `email` value, you want to set the new `email` state value to the new full input value, almost certainly)

You can also avoid this problem by separating out the different stateful values, eg, do:

```
const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
```

```
onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.vaue)}
```

as is usually recommended with hooks.

Comment: Or if you want to keep your state in one object, have interdependence between bits of that state when updating or depend on the previous state when setting the next, `useReducer` is the best way to handle that. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#:~:text=useReducer%20is%20usually%20preferable%20to,dispatch%20down%20instead%20of%20callbacks.

Comment: Thank you! Spread operator works. I appreciate your time and help!